# SELECT MAX Syntax does not return values in stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I am currently working on a web app using vs studio 2015, there is a problem that the stored procedure does not return any values and return `0`. This code was perfectly working on the past few weeks but now, i does not work anymore.

This is my stored procedure:

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO userinfo (empID, badgenum, first_name, address, email, contact_no, birthday, 
                          gender, groupNo, employment_status, userType, SSS, philhealth, 
                          tin, pagibig, hired_date, regularization_date, resigned_date,
                          VLcredit, SLcredit)
    VALUES((SELECT MAX(CAST(empID AS INT) + 1) 
            FROM userinfo), @badgenum, @fName, @Address, @email, @contact, @birthDay, 
            @gender, @group, @stat, @accessType, @sss, @phealth,
            @tin, @pagibig, @hiredDate, @regDate, @resignedDate, @VL, @SL)
END
```

Can someone help me with this? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try running `SELECT MAX(CAST(empID AS INT) + 1) FROM userinfo` separately. Does it return proper value?

Comment: No Sir. It Does not return a value

Comment: Does it return 0 or null or nothing at all? You have rows in userInfo table? What is the data type of empId in the table? What if you just select MAX(empID)?

Comment: I used `int` Sir. Ok I will give it a try.

Comment: It doesn't work also sir.

Comment: it RETURNS 0 sir.

Comment: `It doesn't work also sir` is not clear. You need to tell what exactly is happening. I have asked questions in my comment. Please answer them. Put the details about what you tried in question also.

Comment: Your tags were very disingenuous

Comment: Coming back to @ChetanRanpariya's question. Is there data in userInfo? And is there data in the empID field in the table? This just sounds like a data issue all the way around.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Haven't you try create a simple stored procedure that just return Max value

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

    DECLARE @maxemp INT;

    SELECT MAX(empID) FROM userinfo
END
```

If it returns the expected value, you should try set it on variable then use variable in your stored procedure:

```
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    DECLARE @maxemp INT;

    SELECT @maxemp = MAX(empID) FROM userinfo
    SET @maxemp = @maxemp + 1

    INSERT INTO userinfo(empID,badgenum,first_name,address,email,contact_no,birthday,gender,groupNo,employment_status,
                        userType,SSS,philhealth,tin,pagibig,hired_date,regularization_date,resigned_date,VLcredit,SLcredit)
    VALUES(@maxemp,@badgenum,@fName,@Address,@email,@contact,@birthDay,@gender,@group,@stat,
                        @accessType,@sss,@phealth,@tin,@pagibig,@hiredDate,@regDate,@resignedDate,@VL,@SL)
END
```

Comment: Thank you :) Works like a Charm :D